# Flutter gives "Instance of 'ProgressEvent' " errror when I am trying to send a html request with dart html / universal html

Tags: php, flutter, dart, http

I'm using universal html package which is   same as the dart:html package but work with multiple platforms. From that I'm making this http POST request to my local XAMPP server.

```
Future newConn() async {
    try {
      await html.HttpRequest.postFormData(
        'http://192.166.6.150/test.php',
        {'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Doe'},
      ).then(
        (value) => print("completed$value"),
      );
      ;
    } on Exception {
      print("error");
    }
  }
```

In here $value is the httpResponse object. But when I run the above script flutter gives me "Instance of 'ProgressEvent' " error. I have tried this on my local emulator and chrome both. My php is as below.

test.php

```
<?php

$nameF = $_POST["firstName"];
$nameSec = $_POST["lastName"];


echo $nameF;

exit();

?>
```

Comment: you can use https://pub.dev/packages/dio this plugin .. check the plugin . it will meet you'r requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in `dart:html`. Take a look at the [reported issue on Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60239). There is a [workaround to it in the post here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60239#issuecomment-1135846980). The workaround is as follows:

Check if `isNetworkImageUnauthorizedError(value)` returns `true`. If so, it means `value` is an error:

```dart
bool isNetworkImageUnauthorizedError(dynamic error) {
  if (error is NetworkImageLoadException && error.statusCode == 401) {
    return true;
  }
  //Because of this bug, we need to analyze the error for ProgressEvent
  //https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44370
  //https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60239
  if(error is html.ProgressEvent && error.currentTarget != null) {
    if (error.currentTarget is html.HttpRequest) {
      html.HttpRequest request = error.currentTarget as html.HttpRequest;
      if (request.status == 401) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```